# How to stop AVAudioPlayer from other ViewController?

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I use AVAudioPlayer to play sound on my app. I can stop the sound by just calling a method with `[audioPlayer stop];` in it. But when I call the method from another ViewController the sound is not stopping. I already searched but I can't get the right answer. What I want is to stop the sound from another ViewController. Can someone help me? I am new to iOS.

I used this to add my sound file:

```
//Declare the audio file location and settup the player
NSURL *audioFileLocationURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"alarm" withExtension:@"wav"];
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileLocationURL error:&error];
[audioPlayer setNumberOfLoops:-1];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    [[self volumeControl] setEnabled:NO];
    [[self playPauseButton] setEnabled:NO];
    [[self alertLabel] setText:@"Unable to load file"];
    [[self alertLabel] setHidden:NO];
} else {
    [[self alertLabel] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ has loaded", @"alarm.wav"]];
    [[self alertLabel] setHidden:NO];
    //Make sure the system follows our playback status
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    //Load the audio into memory
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];}
```

And used  `[audioPlayer play];` to start the sound and to stop I used `[audioPlayer stop];`. It is working fine when I am on the same ViewController but when I change ViewController `[myViewController.audioPlayer stop];` is not working. I am using Storyboard with this.

Comment: maybe you need to make a delegate?

Comment: how will I do that? I'm new to iOS so I don't know my way. Can you guide me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0):

You can add the stop method in the current class and call that methos in the other class on button click.Please find the code snippet on the following link

[Trigger AVAudioPlayer to stop all sounds and play selected except when playing(selected) button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357126/trigger-avaudioplayer-to-stop-all-sounds-and-play-selected-except-when-playings)

Adding one more link [Why does the AVAudioPlayer stop method not work when switching views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6714147/why-does-the-avaudioplayer-stop-method-not-work-when-switching-views?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the instance of `AVAudioPlayer` at `.h file` as Global.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AVAudioPlayer *theAudio;
```

You can stop this from another controller

```
[objViewController.theAudio stop];
```

This works for me ..Hope it helps you too..

Comment: I've already tried this but the sound won't stop. I edited my question.